# In Thomas Aquinas's Argument from Degrees, how does he mean that fire is maximally hot and the cause of all heat?

Tags: theology, aquinas

Thomas Aquinas is famous for having made 5 arguments for the existence of God. The weirdest of them is arguably the Argument from Degrees.

To illustrate his point, he claimed, if I correctly understand him, that fire is a maximally hot thing and that fire is also the cause of all heat. What does he mean by that? How can possibly fire be maximally hot when obviously not all fires are equally hot? Some fires can melt steel, while others cannot. And obviously fire is not the cause of all heat as heat can be generated by friction.

Not to mention that we now know that a maximally hot thing, having the Planck Temperature, doesn't exist and has never existed in our universe. And that most of the heat in our universe comes from stars, which aren't fire. And that the centres of stars are way hotter than any fire. But Thomas Aquinas arguably couldn't have known those things.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that they used to think that lightning was a kind of fire (e.g. Dante, in the *Paradiso*, has lightning bolts as effluence from a Sphere of Fire). So Aquinas might be styled as unwittingly thinking something closer to truth than he otherwise sounds like (as if, by comparison, he had accidentally theorized that water was reducible to a combination of two more basic substances, or then per something like an epistemically lucky analytic *a posteriori* comprehension of water).

Comment: Lightning is not infinitely hot either so it's a moot point. We should not be afraid to say that someone is wrong, even if they have great prestige. Most philosophers from centuries ago were just wrong when they speculated about physics or science. Aquinas was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classical and medieval *element of fire* is not the same as *a fire* or *flame*. Flames, like all things below the orbit of the moon, are imperfect combinations of some or all of the four elements. One flame may of course be hotter than another, if it comprises more fire and less earth or water. Likewise when we create heat by friction between solid bodies, we are rubbing together two objects which contain some fire. So while it doesn't confirm that all heat comes from fire, the heat that comes from friction also doesn't disconfirm.

You can get close to what the sentence would have meant to a person seeing the world through the medieval model by restating with a chemical element or a physics concept.

*What moreover is the greatest in its way, in another way is the cause of all things of its own kind; thus elemental oxygen, which is the chemical most oxidized, is the cause of all oxidization of chemicals.*

*...thus point-particles, which are the objects of greatest density, are the cause of all density of objects.*

*...thus propagations of field perturbations, which are the changes of greatest swiftness, are the cause of all swiftness of change.*

---

In case clarification is needed:

The classical and medieval four-elements model of matter was wrong. That is, it was *predictively weak* compared to the other, much more effective models developed later.

Aquinas' claim in the Argument from Degree pretty closely parallels a Platonic theory of Forms. Responses to Aquinas here would either be arguments against the theory of Forms, or an argument that there can be a Form of the Good which is not worth calling God.

Comment: Oxygen is not involved in all oxidation reactions though. I feel it must be stated explicitly that Aquinas was wrong and that the medieval theory of four elements was wrong.

Comment: @causative I have slightly altered and made an addendum above to address your critique.

Comment: @causative I happen to think that all Platonists are wrong about Platonism, but the question was "what does Aquinas mean by this weird claim about fire?" not "is Aquinas right, apart from this weird claim about fire?", so I think this answer is complete without addressing the unasked second question.

Comment: There's a trick where talk show hosts will ask "What does man on the street think about (false conspiracy theory)?" By giving airtime to what other people think about X, without the disclaimer that X is false, they implicitly endorse X. If that's not what you mean to do, best to say so.

Comment: A great name for this is "privileging the lie", and even media like the New York Times and the Washington Post do it. And it can be as subtle as which position gets the headline. But once you start noticing it, you start asking "why aren't you leading with the truth?" a lot.